# SurveyMonkey API v2 returns "Client revoked access grant"

Tags: surveymonkey

Using v2 to get the survey list (https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list) and receiving the error message "Client revoked access grant."  Had just used the same script with the same access key and api key less than 2 months ago without incident.  Have done nothing with the API in the account since, so not understanding why this is not working.  This is on a Gold level account.

I know that it is close to the end of support date on v2 of the API, but my understanding is that date is December 1, 2016.  Besides, I have another account in which I can run the same script (a Premium account with different key values, of course) and it is working for that account.

Comment: did you contact the surveyMonkey support ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is more of a SurveyMonkey support question. There was a widespread issue where people using an invalid access token (generated with the API Console app, not their own app) stopped working.

You can just go to the S[urveyMonkey developer portal](https://developer.surveymonkey.com) and find your app. There will be an access token in the settings page. If your app isn't there, contact support to have it connected to your account.

Comment: Thanks General.  I am working with surveymonkey right now.  Was hoping that I could get a quicker answer here, but at this point in the process, it seems as if the issue is a change on their end they did in preparation to deprecate v2.

Comment: Again, thanks to those who responded/inquired on my question.  Apparently my app and account had been disassociated when they migrated off of Mashery recently.  Hopefully that info may be helpful to those that may have this issue and stumble across this post over the next few weeks until they turn off v2 of the API.